# source code management for windows7 for local used

Tags: github, cvs

I'm using windows 7 and a project in windows. what source code management will I use?
I want a local server.
I try to read this article http://www.tortoisecvs.org/faq.html#win9x but it says that The TortoiseCVS team does not use Vista or Windows 7 and does not have access to a Vista development system. This means that no testing is done on Vista
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) for local source code management. They're real quick and easy to work with, and the entire history of a repository (basically a folder on your hard drive) is contained within the repository itself.

Comment: thanks @Daniel. but can I still commit, push and pull if Im offline if i use git?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the main features of both these systems. And if you want to push the code to a either a server you've setup yourself or a hosting service (like GitHub), you can configure this later on.